# How to find frequent itemset irrespective of attribute name?

Tags: weka, data-mining, apriori

I have a dataset (CSV file) to find frequent itemsets using Apriori algorithm.

```
col1, col2, col3
bread, butter,?
coke, bread, butter
```

I am using WEKA for this purpose. The ouput is in the following format:

```
...
Large Itemsets L(2):
col1=bread  col2= butter 1
col1=coke  col2= bread 1
col1=coke  col3= butter 1
col2= bread  col3= butter 1
...
```

But the output that I am want is :

```
bread, butter 2
```

Basically, the above output is independent of the `col` that they belong to. How can I achieve this kind of output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format your data differently.

Weka expects *columns* to be the same products, and the value to be t/f (for true, false). Then you get itemset of the kind milk=t -> butter=t.

See the .arff examples included with Weka.

I think I saw an ELKI example using your input format.