# Apriori in WEKA

Tags: weka, text-mining, apriori

I'm new to all these Data mining, WEKA Tool etc.,

In my academic project I have to deal with bug reports. I have them in my SQL Server. I took the Bug summary attribute and applied tokenization,stop words removal and stemming techniques.

All the stemmed words in the summary are stored in database ; separated. Now I have to apply **Frequent pattern mining algorithm** and find out **frequent item sets** by using WEKA tool. I have my arff file like this.

```
@relation ItemSets

@attribute bugid integer
@attribute summary string

@data
755113,enhanc;keep;log;recommend;share
759414,access;review;social
763806,allow;intrus;less;provid;shrunken;sidebar;social;specifi
767221,datacloneerror;deeper;dig;framework;jsm
771353,document;integr;provid;secur;social
785540,avail;determin;featur;method;provid;social;whether
785591,chat;dock;horizont;nest;overlap;scrollbar
787767,abus;api;implement;perform;runtim;warn;worker
```

After opening it in Weka, under the **Associate** tab of WEKA Explorer I'm unable to start the process(Start button is disabled) with Apriori selected.

Now please suggest me how to find frequent itemsets on the summary attribute using WEKA. I.m in need of serious help. Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why Apriori is not available using your file in Weka is that Apriori only allows nominal attribute values. What sort of rules are you trying to find? Could you give an example of rules you want to obtain?

```
values_you_want_to_be_the_antecedent_part_of_your_rule ==> values_you_want_to_be_the_consequent_part_of_your_rule
```

Changing your attributes to nominal like this

```
@relation ItemSets

@attribute bugid {755113, 759414, 763806}
@attribute summary {'enhanc;keep;log;recommend;share', 'access;review;social', 'allow;intrus;less;provid;shrunken;sidebar;social;specifi'}

@data
755113,'enhanc;keep;log;recommend;share'
759414,'access;review;social'
763806,'allow;intrus;less;provid;shrunken;sidebar;social;specifi'
```

will only give you rules like

```
bugid=755113 1 ==> summary=enhanc;keep;log;recommend;share 1    <conf:(1)> lift:(3) lev:(0.22)
```

If you're looking for frequent itemsets among the summary words, the bugid is irrelevant and you can remove it from your file. Apriori is used to obtain association rules e.g. `enhanc, keep` gives `log` with support X and confidence Y. To find frequent itemsets, you need to restructure your data so that each summary word is an attribute with values true/false or true/missing, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741464/how-to-find-frequent-itemset-irrespective-of-attribute-name) question.

Try the following file in Weka. Select Associate, choose Apriori, double-click on the white input field next to the Choose button. There, set `outputItemSets` to true. In the console output, you will see all frequent itemsets and all obatined rules with sufficient support.

```
@relation ItemSets

@attribute enhanc {true}
@attribute keep {true}
@attribute log {true}
@attribute recommend {true}
@attribute share {true}
@attribute access {true}
@attribute review {true}
@attribute social {true}
@attribute allow {true}
@attribute intrus {true}
@attribute less {true}
@attribute provid {true}
@attribute shrunken {true}
@attribute sidebar {true}
@attribute specifi {true}


@data
true,true,true,true,true,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
?,?,?,?,?,true,true,true,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
?,?,?,?,?,?,?,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true
```

The questionmarks `?` represent a missing value.

Comment: I just want frequent item sets for a given support count and confidence. Moreover I can't go for nominal attributes because my bugid is auto incremented and summary can't be from a specific set of attributes. It can be any string consisting of any number of words.

Comment: Could you give an example of rules you want to obtain as showed in my edited answer?

Comment: enhanc,browser,js like that I want 2 item set three item set etc.

Comment: But we can't expect the words in the summary. User can give any sort of word. So forming those attributes is difficult. Apriori is not mandatory. Any Algorithm in frequent pattern mining. Like the FP growth.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? Describe the scenario please. I can't help you unless you provide more information.

Comment: I want frequent item sets from that summary column data. Use any sort of fp mining Algorithm

Comment: Yes, I understand that but frequent itemsets can only be mined from a existing source, like a database. As the data is available, you know all possible values of summary words and you can obtain all frequent itemsets as described above.

Comment: I have my data in MS SQL server. I exported it and formed arff file. Yes we can go by above method but it is time taking process and can't be automated by writing code to generate that arff file.

Comment: There is no other way to do it. Either you write your own code to obtain frequent itemsets or restructure your data to fit the above description. I suggest the second choise, takes 2 hours to restructure the data with basic programming skills. Weka comes with a Java library so most of the work is already done.

Comment: Well I'm a beginner in data mining and new to all these. Appreciate your patience in helping me. Thanks!